# Eigenvalues of a Hollow Tridiagonal Matrix in Finite and Infinite Dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, infinite-matrices

I am currently studying a system characterized by a particularly structured matrix, as shown below, $$ \dot{ \boldsymbol{x}} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -2c & \\
c & 0& 3c & \\
&-2c & 0& -4c & \\
& & 3c & 0 & 5c \\
& & & \ddots & \ddots &\ddots
\end{pmatrix}  \boldsymbol{x}.$$
Let's denote this matrix as $cF$. I am particularly interested in the cases where $F$ is $n \times n$ and when it extends to an infinite-dimension. My objectives are to understand any special naming conventions for such matrices and their eigenvalue properties, especially as the dimension varies.

1. Naming and Known Properties: Does this matrix, or ones with a similar structure, have a special name or known properties, such as eigenvalues for the finite-dimensional case? I attempted to factorize $F$ as shown below but didn't manage to derive any conclusion on eigenvalue properties from this factorization: $$ F=\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & -2 & \\
   1 & 0& 3 & \\
   &-2 & 0& -4 & \\
   & & 3 & 0 & 5 \\
   & & & \ddots & \ddots &\ddots
   \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 1 & \\
   1 & 0& 1 & \\
   0 & 1 &\ddots &\ddots\\
    &  & \ddots &
   \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
   1  \\
   & -2 \\
   & & 3 \\
   & & & -4 \\
   & & & & \ddots
   \end{pmatrix} =BD. $$

And I know that $DB=F^\top$. But I could not conclude anything from this expression. I also observed (numerically) that the finite matrix seems to have purely imaginary eigenvalues.

2. Analytical Tools for Infinite-Dimensional Analysis: Considering the difference in the spectrum between finite and infinite-dimensional systems, what analytical tools or approaches could be recommended to study or bound the eigenvalues of the infinite-dimensional system?
   Any insights, suggestions, or references to relevant literature would be extremely helpful and appreciated!